# Is there Any Advantage to Using Multiple Steel Plates in an Electrolyzer?

Tags: electrochemistry, water, electrolysis

If I have an electrolyzer (For water) is there any advantage to having additional steel plates in between the electrodes in solution? For some reason this appears to be a popular design and I'm not sure why. I'd think that at worst the voltage would have to be slightly higher to conduct through the extra solution in a 2 electrode system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the reactions in electrolysis take place on the electrodes surface, it can therefore be concluded, that the more electrode surface (contact surface) exists, the more water molecules can be electrolyzed in one instance of time. Therefore, more steelplates result in more surface, which increases the productivity of the electrolyzer.